# Error in Spark installation --pyspark

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I am installing spark 1.2.1 on windows 8 and I have downloaded a prebuilt package for Hadoop 2.4

When i am running **pyspark** i am getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\Dinesh\Desktop\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4>bin\pyspark
Running python with PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\Dinesh\Desktop\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4\bin\..\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip;C:\Users\Dinesh\Desktop\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4\bin\..\python;
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dinesh\Desktop\spark-1.2.1-bin-Hadoop2.4\bin\..\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 45, in <module>
sc = SparkContext(appName="PySparkShell", pyFiles=add_files)
File "C:\Users\Dinesh\Desktop\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4\python\pyspark\context.py", line 102, in __init__
SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway)
File "C:\Users\Dinesh\Desktop\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4\python\pyspark\context.py", line 212, in _ensure_initialized
SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway()
File "C:\Users\Dinesh\Desktop\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 73, in launch_gateway
raise Exception(error_msg)
Exception: Launching GatewayServer failed with exit code 1!
Warning: Expected GatewayServer to output a port, but found no output.
```

I have searched and i got that in general the error is caused as the path variable are not correctly defined,but i have checked and my variable are all in place. How can i solve the error?
"The system cannot find the path specified." Which path is it talking about.?

Comment: Or at least a hint regarding what may be wrong would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: This problem is happening for me, too, on macbook running ubuntu

Answer (score 7):

In my case the problem came from the terminal I was using. On **Git Bash** on Windows I was getting the error : `line 96: CMD: bad array subscript` when executing `spark-shell`, but when I tried on **PowerShell** it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

The way I debugged this issue was to rem the "@echo off" command on all the command files that got called by pyspark.cmd. 
In the end I nailed it down to me having JAVA_HOME set to "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" which is wrong as one of the cmd scripts adds a "\bin" to JAVA_HOME before calling java.exe and it was triggering the "The system cannot find the path specified." error.
So I changed JAVA_HOME to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25" and it worked fine.

Now I have to un-rem the "@echo off"s. Hope it helps!

Comment: Changing JAVA_HOME to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25" really worked for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It maybe caused by cygwin in the DOS classpath. Spark uses the find command in the file 'spark-class2.cmd', which used then the cygwin find command instead of the DOS find command, which works somewhat different. I removed cygwin from the DOS PATH, which solved the problem.